# Sharepoint Workflow task with title (external participant)

Tags: sharepoint

I made a custom sharepoint workflow with Visual studio, the workflow starts when a new item is inserted in a list

I assigned the title of the task to reference a field in the new item

```
TaskProps.Title = "Please prepare Hardware for project " + workflowProperties.Item["Contract"].ToString().Split('#')[1];
```

the task title is correct but i find the string (exteranl participant) concatenated the title of the task

what can be the reason for this ?

thanks

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly, you're getting something like "Please prepare Hardware for project foo (external participant)" when you should be getting "Please prepare Hardware for project foo"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint thinks that that Variable assigned(User) "Assigned To" is not a internal SharePoint user but external to the environment.